# Recover .tex file after computer crash

Tags: compiling

I was working on my .tex file and had just saved it right before the incident happened, then **BOOM** my computer says something about iqrl. This has been going on for a while and its really temperamental, this is not the problem however. After my computer crashed, the I checked the .tex file to see that it just says NUL everywhere. However, the .dvi file still has all the original content of the document, as if it were never affected. I was wondering if there is any way I could recover my document to its original condition?

Comment: No. You can convert the dvi to pdf and perhaps copy and paste the text. But the structure is gone. Don't you have a backup? Did you look if your editor has made some backups somewhere?

Comment: Make a backup of your working directory on a usb stick and put that into a drawer of your desk before you go on.

Comment: as  Ulrike Fischer said, try to find a (filename).tex.bak in your working directory

Comment: I sympathize.  It turns out that Norton does not recognize .tex as a file type to be backed up unless you specifically enter it.  I wound up restoring lots of files from PDFs.

Answer (score 3):

In such cases you have the following oportunities:

- Your used editor (you didn't tell the name) creates a backup file, for example `mwe.bak` or `mwe.tex.bak`.  If the `mwe.tex` is corrupted, rename the backup file and continue working with this version. The changes you made since the start of the editor, will be lost. 
  (**Conclusion**: Use an editor with that functionality!)
- Your used editor had not created an backup file, but you have a second (mobile) hard disk drive or an USB stick containing the latest version of your work, for example the complete directory. Then you can use this backup and you have only lost the work of one day. 
  (**Conclusion**: You should do this **every** day, and would be best practise if you have one separate disk drive or USB stick for each working day!)
- Your used editor had not created an backup file, but you have a daily backup of your system with any backup software. Recreate the missing file and go on.  You have lost all the work done since the last system backup.
  (**Conclusion**: backup your system each day, for example in the evening after work. After backup the computer can do a shut down.)
- Your used editor had no backup file created and you have no program used for backup.  Then you should stop working with the computer, do not start it and visit an computer expert. If you are lucky, he can restore the corrupted file.  But that only works if you do not make any changes on the computer and can cost a lot of money!  (**Conclusion**: avoid to get in that situation)

**To summarize the conclusions above**: Best would be to use an editor creating an `.bak` file and backup your system once each day!

But this is more a computer usage question, not really an TeX or LaTeX question, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the corrupted ".tex" file and select "Restore previous versions". The file restores to the last version. Run that file. you will get at least 95% of your original file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. To which editor does this advice apply?

Answer (score 0):

If you have windows configured to create restore points periodically, and the incident didn't happen long ago, you can always go to windows explorer, locate the .tex file, right click on it, and choose "Restore previous versions". If you are lucky, a recent version of your file can be recovered, I just did that with a very important file.