# Text line contains an invalid character

Tags: math-mode

I am having a problem with TeX studio. The data on the editor has suddenly disappeared and there is an error of invalid characters. I don't know how to fix it because I can not see anything on the editor. Here is the snapshot:

[image]

Comment: This happened when I was writing some mathematical equations and suddenly my laptop goes off due to the battery drain and when I restarted it was giving this kind of error.

Comment: We can't see `Chapter4.tex` (the file LaTeX complains about) in the screenshot, but I'm afraid it looks as though the file is corrupted and can't be read by TeX. It might be time to bring out your backups. If you don't have a backup your options are probably quite limited: https://superuser.com/q/377904, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234224/35864. But you should definitely see if your editor (TeXStudio? TeXmaker?) might have saved a backup copy of the file somewhere. Look for a `.bak` or a file with a `~` in its name.